# Create data frame from another data frame

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, reshape

I have below data frame

```
df1:
Q1(25%)  Q2(50%)    Q3(75%)
438.55   654.78     870.34
```

in df1 Q1(25%), Q2(50%), Q3(75%) are column names.
want to convert the above data frame df1 as below

```
df2:
quant     points
25         438.55
50         654.78
75         870.34
```

Comment: Paste the output of `dput(df1)` into your question.

Comment: Try `setNames(stack(df)[2:1], c("quant", "points"))`

Comment: I need quant column as an integer and values should be 25, 50, 75 not q25, q50, q75

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `stack()` and extract the 2-digit numbers from the `quant` column.

```r
transform(
  setNames(stack(df)[2:1], c("quant", "points")),
  quant = as.integer(regmatches(quant, regexpr("\\d{2}", quant)))
)

#   quant points
# 1    25 438.55
# 2    50 654.78
# 3    75 870.34
```

###### Data

```r
df <- data.frame("Q1(25%)" = 438.55, "Q2(50%)" = 654.78, "Q3(75%)" = 870.34,
                 check.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to go from wide form of data to long form of data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(q25 = 123, q50 = 345, q75 = 678)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "quant", values_to = "points")

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   quant points
#>   <chr>  <dbl>
#> 1 q25      123
#> 2 q50      345
#> 3 q75      678
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>